# How to get access token using refresh token in google oauth2?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-api, refresh-token

I have google drive sign in feature in my react nodejs application. When ever a user clicks on sign in, I am using Google oauth2 to get code and that to get access token and refresh token using client ID and secret. I am saving these tokens and expiry in my database. Now, I want to use the refresh to get access token so that my access token never expires. Basically, I want the user to be always signed in.
I am creating a post request to token to get the access token using the refresh token. This is my code:

```
try{ 
 axios.post('/https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',{
  client_id: clientId,
  client_secret: secret,
  refresh_token: rToken
  grant_type: rToken
 })
 .then((response) => { 
  console.log("response = ", response)
 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log("error in getting token: = ", error)
 })
} catch(err) { 
 console.log("error = ", err)
}
```

I am getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I tried passing grant_type: refresh_token buy this gave reference error: refresh_token is not defined

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using the axios.post() method to make a request to the Google OAuth2 token endpoint, but the URL you provided is incorrect. The correct URL for the token endpoint is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token, not /https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token.

Here is an example of how you could correctly make a request to the Google OAuth2 token endpoint to get an access token using a refresh token:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const clientId = 'your-client-id';
const secret = 'your-client-secret';
const rToken = 'your-refresh-token';

try {
  axios.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', {
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: secret,
    refresh_token: rToken,
    grant_type: 'refresh_token'
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("response = ", response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error in getting token: = ", error);
  });
} catch(err) {
  console.log("error = ", err);
}
```